# Confusion about getBoundingClientRect, .getSelection , .getRangeAt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `.getSelection` to get selected text then use `.getRangeAt(0)` and then use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to obtain the position of window.

Below is my working code.

```
function getText(){
  if(window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection();
  } 
}

$("#textArea").mouseup(function(){
    var selection = getText();
    var oRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    var oRect = oRange.getBoundingClientRect();

    var left = oRect.left
    var top = oRect.top
}
```

My questions are:

Why I "cannot" directly use like?

```
mySelectedText.getSelection().getBoundingClientRect();
```

Why I have to use `.getRangeAt()`;

What is the difference between these three functions?

1. `.getSelection`
2. `.getRangeAt`
3. `.getBoundingClientRect`

Answer (score 0):

getBoundingClientRect is the offset of the Element any Element,
getSelection and getRangeAt work with the caret and the not return an Element they return a Selection Object and a Range Object